# Working of conditional compilation #if and #else (and others) in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

I tried to write a program using some conditional compilation pre-processing directives instead of "if-else" as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int x;
    scanf ("%d",&x);
#if (x==5)
    printf ("x is 5");
#else
    printf ("x not 5");
#endif
}
```

But the thing is, it always print the else part even though value of `x`is `5`. My simplest question is----->**WHY?**

Is it possible to successfully complete this program (i.e taking value of x from user and check conditions using #if directive and print statement under #if).

During compilation it shows a warning ***"'x' is not defined, evaluates to 0"***. But `x` seems defined to me. Does that mean `x` should be defined using `#define`. Please explain me concept behind Conditional Compilation.

Comment: The preprocessor cannot use variables from the C program.

Comment: The preprocessor runs during compilation. To check runtime values use normal `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessing takes place **before** the compilation. So preprocessor does not know anything about your C code or variables. You cant use any C variables in conditions.

Conditional compilation is for different purposes.

```
#define DEBUG

/* ....*/ 

#ifdef DEBUG 
printf("Some debug value %d\n", val);
#endif
```

Comment: If preprocessing takes place before the compilation, why does compiling the two lines `void a[3];` and `#error` with Clang produce an error message for the first line (array has incomplete element type) before an error message for the second line?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: there's the _as if_ rule.  The compiler is allowed to do things differently, and does not need to run the whole preprocessor phase before doing semantic analysis.  The standard doesn't prohibit what you say you expect; it doesn't prohibit what you report happens, either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I did not ask why the C standard permits this. I asked how P__J__’s statement is consistent with Clang behavior. The C standard’s specification is consistent with Clang’s behavior in this regard. Asserting that preprocessing takes place before compilation is not consistent with Clang’s behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil clang is not conforming in this case: *The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit
containing a #error preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by
conditional inclusion.*

Comment: @EricPostpischil standard in **5.1.1.2** *Translation phases* shows that the preprocessing takes place **before** the compilation. Step 7: *The resulting tokens are
syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.*

Comment: @P__J__: 5.1.1.2 specifies the **precedence** of translation phases, not the chronological order: “The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following phases.” It is incorrect and misleading to state that preprocessing takes place before compilation. This false statement could mislead a person who sees a message about a phase 7 error to conclude that preprocessing finished successfully, and therefore there are no phase 1-6 errors.

Comment: @EricPostpischil clang is not conforming in this case *The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a #error preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion.*

Comment: @P__J__: It is conforming because the translation unit is not successfully translated.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not an integer literal or an integer literal expression (integer literals + operators) or a macro expanding to those, so in a conditional, the preprocessor replaces it with `0` ([6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4)). `0==5` is false, so the `#else` branch is taken.

The preprocessor doesn't know about C declarations, types and such. It only works with tokens (and macros that ultimately expand to those).

---

[6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4)

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including
>   those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number
>   0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've added a quote from the standard to support that claim.  ;-) (You now owe me an upvote :P).

Comment: TIL! I'd headed to Coliru to gather incriminating evidence against you, and left in shock :P Thanks for the ref

Answer (score 0):

Operands in `#if` statements can be only constants, things defined with `#define`, and a special `defined` operator. Any other identifiers in the expression are replaced with 0. The `x` in your sample code is not defined with `#define`, so `(x==5)` becomes `(0==0)`.

In the C 2018 standard, clause 6.10.1 tells us that evaluation of the expression in an `#if` statement includes:

- Preprocessor macros (things defined with `#define`) are replaced according to their definitions.
- Uses of the `defined` operator are replaced with 0 or 1.
- Any remaining identifiers are replaced with 0.

Because the `x` in your sample code is not defined with `#define`, it is replaced with 0 in the `#if` statement. This results in `(0==5)`, which is false, so code between the `#if` and the `#else` is skipped.

In a preprocessor statement, you cannot evaluate variables based on values that will be set during program execution.

Answer (score -1):

It's the "pre-processor". "Pre" means "before".

You're trying to use a *runtime* value during preprocessing! The preprocessor of course has no access to that information during the build.

This problem isn't limited to runtime values, but is more fundamental. Even if you were trying to use a (named) compile-time constant such as `constexpr int x = 2`, you couldn't do that. These are two languages interleaving, like generating HTML with PHP; the HTML has no knowledge of PHP variables, and the PHP has no knowledge of what widgets the user clicks on the page. These are completely different execution contexts with no built-in interaction or cross-compatibility.

Comment: Curious about the downvotes, personally. I thought this was a decent analogy.

Comment: By distinguishing “pre-processor,” this answer tells us there is preprocessor activity and there is processor activity and that preprocessor activity happens before processor activity, but it does not tell us what is in preprocessor activity and what is in processor activity. So it does not tell the OP that `x == 5` can be evaluated only during processor activity if `x` is not a preprocessor identifier. It does not even distinguish what is a preprocessor identifier from other types of identifiers.

Comment: Also, it is incorrect that “Even if you were trying to use a compile-time constant,” it would not work, because `2+2+1` is a compile-time constant but may also be used in preprocessor expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A compile-time constant such as `constexpr int x = 2`, that does not and can not have any runtime component but is nonetheless completely invisible to the preprocessor. So, let's change it to "named compile-time constant".

Comment: @EricPostpischil And I didn't get your first comment so maybe you could rewrite it? No I did not go into an academic exploration of the kinds of identifiers - I don't find that this warrants -2 though.

Comment: C does not have `constexpr`. C allows a grammatical *constant-expression* in `#if` statements, except that, after macro expansion and processing of `defined`, all remaining identifiers are replaced with 0.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, you have told OP that something happens before something else, but you have not said what each something is. Since the semantics were unknown to OP, let’s use terms you do not know the meaning of to illustrate, say “glurmf” and “zugmar.” OP was unaware that `int x` defined an `x` that is known only to the zugmar, but that `#if` is processed by the glurmf. Your answer simply does not say that an identifier `x` declared with `int x` will be treated as zero during glurmf. Telling the OP that glurmf is before zugmar does not inform them of this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does not say that because that misrepresents the situation. The identifier `x` declared with `int x` has nothing to do with the `x` found in the glumf, because it's evaluated in an entirely different context. That's the point of the problem, and that's what I [tried to] explain. :) Anyway, we can agree to disagree. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Re “The identifier x declared with `int x` has nothing to do with the x found in the glumf, because it's evaluated in an entirely different context.”: The answer does not say that. The information is simply missing from the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, it does - by analogy with PHP and HTML which exist in the exact same circumstance. As I said, we can simply agree to disagree now. Have a good evening.

Comment: Suppose I had never seen C before but knew PHP and HTML. What text in your answer tells me whether `int x` is in the PHP analog or in the HTML analog?